# why is "know" expressed as 知っています, and what does 知ります really mean?

Tags: usage, verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is 知りません the negative form of　知っています？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5729/why-is-%e7%9f%a5%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93-the-negative-form-of%e3%80%80%e7%9f%a5%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%be%e3%81%99%ef%bc%9f)

I'm posting the question as suggested by Zhen Lin and troyen. What that said, why is that? And a secondary question, when would you use 知ります?

[Related post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5729/769)

Comment: Isn’t this a duplicate of the other question?  I cannot imagine any answer to either question which does not answer the other.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I'm sure the answers are related, if not tightly coupled, but still it is a different question.

Comment: In case it was unclear, my point is that I cannot imagine any answer other than “Read the answers to the other question.”