# What is 在り方 used for?

Tags: word-choice

Consider the extracted original Japanese text [from the translation attempt in "Why is 知りません the negative form of　知っています？"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5750/542) :

> これは「知る」という動詞の"意味特徴"と、私たちが「知る」に抱く"イメージ=認知の在り方"に原因があると考えるのが妥当だと思う｡

Also consider [this proposed translation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4931327#4931327):

> "Regarding this fact, I think it is appropriate to think that it is due to the 'semantic features' of the verb '知る' and the image (= the way we perceive) that we have against '知る'.

Isn't "the way we ～" for する-nouns expressed using `～の仕方`? How is it different from `～の在り方`?

Can the same difference be reflected in other verbs? 
 
I.e. if for する-nouns there is a "pair" like `認知の在り方`/`認知の仕方` then is there a similar "pair" concept for verbs like `書く`? If `書き方` is analogous to `～仕方`, what form of `書く` is analogous to `～在り方`?

What is `～在り方` used for?

Comment: 1. `書きの在り方` as well as `書きの仕方` are ungrammatical. 2.  If what you meant by "expressed using `～の仕方`" was `認知の仕方`, then `認知` is a する-noun, not する-verb.

Comment: There is `書き方`, but I cannot think of a counterpart with `仕方`.

Comment: If 書き方 is analogous to X仕方, what form of 書く is analogous to X在り方?

Comment: I meant I cannot think of a counterpart with `在り方`. It was a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the literal idea of `在り方` is 'the way it came into existence', 'the way it should exist', and it is concerned with the meta level of the way of doing something. As opposed to `仕方` 'way of doing', `在り方` may be translated as 'the way it is designed to do', 'the way it should be done', etc.

For verbs not derived from suru-nouns, you can add `-方` to their stem: `書き方`. If you want to use a counterpart to `在り方`, you would have to find a noun with the corresponding concept. You may not be able to find an exact counterpart, though: `[書]{しょ}の在り方` 'the way calligraphy should be', `[書]{しょ}[物]{もつ}の在り方` 'the way books should be'.