# Still confused with tenses

Tags: grammar, tense

Which is the correct one?

- テレビが壊れ**ている**から、見られ**ない**んです。
- テレビが壊れ**ている**から、見られ**ていない**んです。
- テレビが壊れ**る**から、見られ**ない**んです。
- テレビが壊れ**る**から、見られ**ていない**んです。
- テレビが壊れ**た**から、見られ**ない**んです。
- テレビが壊れ**た**から、見られ**ていない**んです。

When do we have to use either progressive or plain form such as in the following sentences?

- このことを知っていますか。
- このことを知りますか。
- 部屋の窓がいつも閉まるから、旅行しているかもしれない。
- 部屋の窓がいつも閉まっているから、旅行しているかもしれない。
- 部屋の窓がいつも閉まるから、旅行するかもしれない。
- 部屋の窓がいつも閉まっているから、旅行するかもしれない。

Comment: Βy the way, it should be 閉まっている and not 閉まている

Comment: I think that the questions about 知る would have best been asked separately, partly because 知る is somewhat special. (http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5729/why-is-%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93-the-negative-form-of-%E7%9F%A5%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99). Unfortunately, there are already two answers addressing that part of the question...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As for your broken TV, all sentences are correct and are emphasizing different aspects of your problem. Let me give some loose translations and try to illustrate the differences.

- > テレビが壊れ**ている**から、見られ**ない**んです。
  >   My TV is broken, so I can't watch TV.

  The progressive tense emphasizes the ongoing state of "being broken". You intend to repair your TV, but in the meantime, you can't watch TV. You can't watch the episode you wanted, but you don't sound too troubled by that.
- > テレビが壊れ**ている**から、見られ**ていない**んです。
  >   My TV is broken, so I haven't been able to watch TV [or rather *anything*].

  Again, you intend to repair your TV, but now the progressive tense in the second half of the sentence means that you also feel the length of "not being able to watch". (You can't watch *anything* while your TV is broken.)
- > テレビが壊れ**る**から、見られ**ない**んです。
  >   I can't watch TV, because [whenever I try to watch TV] my TV breaks. *or*
  >   I can't watch TV, because [I think] my TV is going to break.

  This and the next are a bit strange, because the plain form of 壊れる means either that "every time you watch TV, your TV breaks" or that you're worried that your TV will break. (Cf. 壊れるから、触らないで! "Don't touch, it's gonna break!")
- > テレビが壊れ**る**から、見られ**ていない**んです。
  >   My TV always breaks, so I haven't been able to watch TV.

  Again, your TV either breaks every time you try to watch (strange), or you're worried it does (also a little strange), and you're troubled by the fact that you can't watch anything.
- > テレビが壊れ**た**から、見られ**ない**んです。
  >   My TV broke, so I can't watch TV.

  Your TV broke and it doesn't sound like it's something that you're going to (try to) repair. As a simple consequence, you can't watch TV.
- > テレビが壊れ**た**から、見られ**ていない**んです。
  >   My TV broke, so I haven't been able to watch TV [or watch *anything*].

  This is the most hopeless of them all. Your TV is broken beyond repair, and as a consequence you lost your link to civilization. [Replace this by a more reasonable interpretation, by analogy with the above.]

There are other reasons for choosing one tense over the other. For 壊れる one is more likely to say 壊れている, because 壊れた sounds very careless, in the sense of "broken and nothing I'm going to do about it". 壊れている sounds more like you're trying to get it fixed. (Try it with 車 or トイレ!)

---

Just briefly,

1. 部屋の窓がいつも閉まるから、旅行しているかもしれない。
2. 部屋の窓がいつも閉まっているから、旅行しているかもしれない。
3. 部屋の窓がいつも閉まるから、旅行するかもしれない。
4. 部屋の窓がいつも閉まっているから、旅行するかもしれない。

(2) is the only real option. いつも閉まる, as in (1) and (3) would mean "always [opening and] closing" (or "always closes [whenever I look]") which doesn't make any sense. And (4) would be "The window is always closed, so he might travel soon." Why would someone close his windows days or weeks before travelling?

Answer (score 3):

They are all correct, and you should use it depending on what you want to say.

1. テレビが壊れているから、見られないんです。
   We can't watch it because the TV has been broken (and is currently out of order).
2. テレビが壊れているから、見られていないんです。
   We haven't been able to watch it because the TV has been broken.
3. テレビが壊れるから、見られないんです。
   We can't watch it because the TV will be broken (if we watch it).
4. テレビが壊れるから、見られていないんです。
   We haven't been able to watch it because the TV will be broken.
5. テレビが壊れたから、見られないんです。
   We can't watch it because the TV got broken.
6. テレビが壊れたから、見られていないんです。
   We haven't been able to watch it because the TV got broken.
7. このことを知っていますか。 Do you know this?
8. このことを知りますか。 Will you learn this?
9. 部屋の窓がいつも閉まるから、旅行しているかもしれない。 Since the window in the room closes every time, they might be on a trip.
10. 部屋の窓がいつも閉まっているから、旅行しているかもしれない。 Since the window in the room has been closed every time, they might be on a trip.
11. 部屋の窓がいつも閉まるから、旅行するかもしれない。 Since the window in the room closes every time, they might take a trip.
12. 部屋の窓がいつも閉まっているから、旅行するかもしれない。 Since the window in the room has been closed every time, they might take a trip.