# What is the difference between ～ていてください and ～ていってください?

Tags: translation, word-choice, nuances, verbs, subsidiary-verbs

a.**ゆっくりしていてください**

b.**ゆっくりしていってください**

What's the difference between these two sentences? How to translate them?

Comment: Just to make sure. Are you aware that していて is して+subsidiary verb いる(居る) and していって is して+subsidiary verb いく(行く)?

Comment: @Chocolate Yeah. I met the first sentence at first, but I didn't know the meaning of it. Then I googled it. And the results are almost about the second sentence. So I asked this question here.

Comment: Ahh yes yes, the second sentence is used far more often in real life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a.ゆっくりして**いて**ください

I believe this is standard [-ている](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43190/the-use-of-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B) (sometimes called progressive tense), i.e.

> "Please be relaxed/take it easy" [and stay that way].

---

> b.ゆっくりして**いって**ください

`ていって` has several possible interpretations:

1. conjugation of -ていく (changing state)

> "Please relax/become relaxed"(?)

Although i think -ていく is mostly used in descriptions (e.g. `空が明るくなっていく`) and not much in requests so this one is unlikely IMO.

2. (most likely) conjugation of ‐て行く (do an action and leave/opposite of -て来る):

> "Please take it easy [before you have to go]"

3. conjugation of ‐て言う, but it doesn't really work in this example IMO.
4. a few more options like 入って,云って,要って  but these are even less plausible

For more info:

- [Difference between -ていく and -てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/676/difference-between-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%8f-and-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8b)
- [The use of "ている"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43190/the-use-of-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b)
- [What is a subsidiary verb?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18952/what-is-a-subsidiary-verb)

Comment: bの解釈は、「2. conjugation of ‐て行く (do an action and leave...) "Please take it easy before you have to go"」が最もよいと思います

Answer (score 0):

いって is in a kind of the future tense, いて is in the present tense.
The difference is the person the speaker is talking to is already "staying" or, "not staying yet" or the speaker is not sure whether they will stay.

Comment: Could you translate these two sentences in English?

Comment: My attempt is: a. Please make yourself comfortable. b. Please stay here as long as you want and make yourself comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

a. You could say this to a person who is trying to help you. ゆっくりしていてください is a polite way to say "Thank you but you don't have to do that. "

b. You say ゆっくりしていってください to a guest of your family etc. Let's say the guest is a colleague of your partner. You intervene their conversation perhaps to say hello or to serve some drinks. ゆっくりしていってください means something like "Have a good time. I won't bother you any more."