# 「って云って下さい」に関する質問

Tags: grammar, literature

> ..つい電話口で洩らしてしまった。
>
> 「今日は岡本へ行かなければならないから、そちらへは参りません**って云って下さい**」
>
> それで病院の方を切った**彼女**は、すぐ岡本へかけ易えて、今に行ってもいいかと聞き合せた。そうして最後に呼び出した津田の妹へは、彼の現状を一口報告的に通じただけで、また宅へ帰った。...

-夏目漱石『[明暗](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000148/files/782_14969.html#midashi580)』より

質問は、

「彼女」は津田の妻「お延」ですか。

もう一つの質問は「って云って下さい」のところです。この「って云って下さい」はどう理解すればいいですか。

[What is the difference between ～ていてください and ～ていってください?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/47335/what-is-the-difference-between-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84-and-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84/47340#47340)

この答えは「ていってください」に関するのがありますが、「入って,云って,要って」に対する解釈は

> a few more options like 入って,云って,要って but these are **even less plausible**

なので、この質問に答えられません。

もしかしてお延の自分の夫津田への要求や命令などと理解するのでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「彼女」は津田の妻「お延」です。

この「って云って下さい」は、「と伝えてください。」という意味です。
辞書には、「云う」の意味は、「人のいったことや伝聞したことなどを引いて・・・・という。」と書いてありました。