# 知りませんでした or 知っていませんでした?

Tags: verbs, て-form

> A 「宿題はもう出しましたか」
> B 「いいえ。昨日宿題がありましたか。私は___」
>
> 1. 知りませんでした
> 2. 知っていませんでした
> 3. 覚えません
> 4. 覚えませんでした

I am a little confused because I don't quite catch the difference between the first two options. There was a similar exercise before and I think I ended up using the -te imasu form but now I am doubting it. They give us a lot of multiple choices with all the grammar until now (N5, although sometimes there are from upper levels in-between) and for some reason they are all hiragana.

Comment: [Does it help?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5729/)

Answer (score 4):

I am Japanese and I've been learning English for a few years but I'm not good at English.

First one is correct and second one is incorrect due to Japanese people never say "知っていませんでした".
I think "知っていませんでした" is weird.
I'm sorry I cannot explain the reason why I think it's weird correctly but I can tell you some correct forms like below.

We always say like this and this means we never says another forms.
Positive form
1."知っています"
2."知っている"
3.”知ってる”
Negative form
4."知らない"
5."知りません"

If you have any question, please feel free to contact me and I will investigate and tell you as much as I can

Answer (score 0):

The way I think about this (native English speaker) is

しっています implies on going “knowing” of said thing. I know (and always will know) Tanaka-san.

しっていません would therefore imply ongoing not and therefore never knowing. IE “I’ll never know” Tanaka-san but presumably in Japanese it’s more akin to expressing that void of knowledge can never be filled and therefore you’d never say it.

Therefore しらない implies to me “I don’t, yet know” but that may change. IE I haven’t yet met Tanaka-san.